# Javascript variable not defined error

Tags: javascript

i have the following code:

```
// Get combination prices
var combID = $('#idCombination').val();
var combinationsFromController;
var combination = combinationsFromController[combID];

if (typeof combination === 'undefined')
    return;

// Set product (not the combination) base price
var basePriceWithoutTax = +productPriceTaxExcluded;
var basePriceWithTax = +productPriceTaxIncluded;
var priceWithGroupReductionWithoutTax = 0;
```

When i execute it, Chrome always complaints that:

```
combinationsFromController is not defined.
```

Can anyone help me why is this happening ?

I tried:

```
var combinationsFromController = new Array();
var combination = combinationsFromController[combID];
```

with no luck.

Comment: It should return `not defined.` What do you expect it to return?

Answer (score 0):

You never defined combinations from controller.

```
var combinationsFromController;
// combinationsFromController is undefined because you did not give it a value
```

You have to give variables a value before you can use them.

You probably want

```
var combinationsFromController = getCombitationsFromController()
```

Replace `getCombitationsFromController()` with the code to get the combinations from the controller.

Comment: That is actually from Prestashop 1.6.1.4. I tried to declare it as empty array but it still throws error.

Comment: @JeremyRIrawan what is the code to get the combinations from the controller?